# Is there any kind of file that can hold calendar information (appointments or so)?

Tags: calendar, file-extension

I am looking for a type of file that can hold calendar information (such as appointments) and when opened by a calendar application (such as outlook or similar apps) either on desktop or mobile it will be added to the user calendar (of course after the user's permission)? Or is there a standard CSV format that calendar apps agree on?

The idea behind this is to give the employees the ability to download their monthly schedule through the company's website using this file format and update their own calendars at once. I know I can update their company calendar (exchange) directly but I want this option to be available as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for the [ICalendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) file format. These files are frequently shared as .ics files, although for the use case you describe it might be more convenient to create a calendar on the web, for example in Google Calendar, which the user subscribes to in the calendar client (e.g. Outlook).